# How to get BottomNavigation item view reference for TapTargetView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a Bottom Navigation View and I'm using TapTargetView library to guide the user on how to use certain features. If I pass the Bottom Navigation View then TapTargetView will highlight the whole bottom bar which I don't want that.

My question is how can I highlight the specific item in the Bottom Navigation View?

```
TapTargetView.showFor(this, TapTarget.forView(findViewById(R.id.home), "Home page", "We have cool features for you"),
new TapTargetView.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
        super.onTargetClick(view);
        itemClicked();
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution, here is it:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
TapTargetView.showFor(this, TapTarget.forView(bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.home), "Home page", "We have cool features for you"),
        new TapTargetView.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
                super.onTargetClick(view);
                itemClicked();
            }
        });
```

Comment: It would be nice to show where R.id.home is defined, is it a menu item id?

Comment: @androidguyit's the menu id but, it looks like chopped with me

Comment: @dave any idea how to make the view fill the whole bottom nav instead of shopping as other items title are shown

Answer (score 0):

I havent actually tried this, but i think this should work

```
TapTargetView.showFor(this, TapTarget.forView(YOURBOTTOMNAVIGATIONVIEW.getChildAt(YOUR VIEW POSITION), "Home 
page", "We have cool features for you"),
new TapTargetView.Listener() {
@Override
public void onTargetClick(TapTargetView view) {
    super.onTargetClick(view);
    itemClicked();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried that but it didn't work...the TapTargetView  highlight is not showing in the screen

Comment: Is the view null?

Comment: I don't think the view is null otherwise app will crash instantly, but in my case, the app is working fine but the highlight is not showing at all